# CSS trying to line up three iamges

Tags: css

I'm trying to add three images from left to right. And for some reason that I can not figure out they wont line up. I'm not a pro by no means. I know just enough to be dangerous as I'm sure you'll be able to see.

```css
Add here is the CSS for above. 
.header-ad {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -105px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.head-left {
 display: -webkit-inline-box;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.head-right {
 display: -webkit-inline-box;
 float: right;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: -115px;
    margin-bottom: -20px; 
}
```

```html
</header>
 <div class="head-left">
 <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://amorosso.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/L14-30.png"></a>
 </div>
 <?php if(!empty($mts_options['mts_header_adcode'])) { ?>
  <div class="header-ad">
   <?php echo do_shortcode($mts_options['mts_header_adcode']); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="head-right">
  <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://amorosso.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/L14-30.png"></a>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Any help on this would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong in the basic idea of floating items.

You should think like "I got a box and want to put three items in a row into the box".

Use the float: left on all items (to align them, side by side).

```
.head {
  width: 100%
  height: 236px;
}
.head div {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.head div:last-child {
  float: right;
}
.col25 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col50 {
  width: 48%;
  padding: 0 1%;
}

<div class="head">
  <div class="head-left col25">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://amorosso.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/L14-30.png"></a>
  </div>
  <?php if(!empty($mts_options['mts_header_adcode'])) { ?>
  <div class="header-ad col50">
    <?php echo do_shortcode($mts_options['mts_header_adcode']); ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="head-right col25">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://amorosso.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/L14-30.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit:
In this case you can add specific width for the elements.
add class col25 to the left and right header and col50 to header-ad.
Add those classes to your css (updated code).
I also added a min-height / height for the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
.header-ad {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -105px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

width should not be 100% (put it in pixels) as it would take the entire width and move the other images to the next row.

You alsos don't need `display: -webkit-inline-box;` property if you are using floats.